# ToC pdf bookmark missplaced anchor

Tags: bookmarks

I want to add the table of contents to the bookmarks to facilitate navigation in the pdf. I managed to do so but the behaviour of said bookmark is inconsistant with the others as it anchors below the title of the toc and not directly to it (i.e. The "Contents" title is masked, only displaying the actual content of the ToC).

Any way to fix that?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect{\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\usepackage{tocbibind}` working for you instead of using `\addtocontents`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It does indeed work but it also adds a line for Contents in the ToC which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inserts the bookmark and the relevant hypertarget such that it jumps to `Contents`, i.e. the heading of the `Contents` page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Another solution: Use `etoolbox` and `\preto` in order to prepend code to `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\preto{\tableofcontents}{\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does work as intended, but it requires the statement to be passed after the beginning of the document which I would prefer to avoid. I am trying to develop a framework for documents which I include in the preamble. Any way to circumvent that?

Comment: @Florian: Did you specify that in your question? ;-) No, you didn't.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct as I stated. I was just wondering if you knew another way.

Comment: @Florian: See the edit

Comment: Thank you so much. I had similar issues with other commands and this is going to solve a lot them.